# How to install GeoServer on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit?

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu

- I borrowed the user name from friend.

I need to install GeoServer on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.

first, I installed Oracle Java 7 (JRE/JDK) successfully.

then, i thought i need to install JAI and ImageIO (jre and jdk amd 64-bit) from here
http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/

http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/

following these instructions :
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#installing-native-jai-on-linux

but that didn't work.

then tried these instructions (for JAI files) :
http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/INSTALL-1_1_2.html#Installation

install done but with these errors :

Cannot create lib/amd64/libmlib_jai.so

Cannot create lib/ext/jai_core.jar

Cannot create lib/ext/jai_codec.jar

Cannot create lib/ext/mlibwrapper

also when i tried to install IimageIO files i got: Please do not attempt to install this archive file

I am not sure what to do now.

maybe it is better if i use 32 bit machine instead of 64 bit ?
or use openJDK instead of oracle java ?
I really need your suggestions ppl.

Comment: do i have to install JAIs while I am working on Vector Layers and WFS protocols only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to install JAI and ImageIO in order to run GeoServer. These two libraries are used by GeoServer "only" to improve the raster processing performance, but are not needed for vector layers.

If you need JAI and ImageIO later i.e. after installing GeoServer, it is still possible to install them.

Comment: i see. Thank you. but what about these configurations that allow for fast statup. would i be able to apply it without JAI ? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html

Comment: Yes, these optimisation hints do not affect JAI.